# Outdated links in our posts

Tags: discussion

Are there any tools available for monitoring "broken" or outdated links on the forum?

I find myself having to click my Answers occasionally, and find that the documentation has either been retired or updated. In order to avoid coding something to do this I was wondering if any of you use any existing tools or if there is something on the site that checks for these links and notifies moderators who in exchange notify the us =P

Comment: Just people visiting them again and leaving comments pretty much.

Comment: You must be talking about Marketing Cloud wiki links :/